# Fill gallery rectangle based on value power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

Trying to fill a rectangle shape in a gallery based on a selection.

Using formula below, but not working:

```
If(ThisItem.'Risk Status'.Value="OPEN",RGBA(235, 130, 125, 1), Or(ThisItem.'Risk Status'.Value="CLOSED", RGBA(115, 205, 170, 1), Or(ThisItem.'Risk Status'.Value="VALIDATED",  RGBA(255, 153, 51, 1))
```

Could anyone help? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below formula:

```
If(ThisItem.'Risk Status'.Value = "OPEN", RGBA(235, 130, 125, 1), ThisItem.'Risk Status'.Value = "CLOSED", RGBA(115, 205, 170, 1), ThisItem.'Risk Status'.Value = "VALIDATED", RGBA(255, 153, 51, 1), RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1))
```

I have added default color as `RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1)` at the end of the formula. You can change it as per your requirements or skip it.

**Documentations**:

1. [If and Switch functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)

Comment: Thanks a million ganesh! it worked nicely